# Using parents for drawable resources

Tags: android, styles, drawable

When I define a style, it can be inherited from a parent style, e.g:

```
<style name="DialogNoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to do the same with drawable resources, something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" name="ChildDrawable" parent="@drawable/ParentDrawable">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: what exactly would the child drawable inherit from the parent drawable?

Comment: Everything, and then I decide what to override, just like inheritance in styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - you cannot extend and override drawables. However,

- Some drawables can be created from other drawables. e.g. layer-list will allow you to draw layers of drawables one on top of another. Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html .
- You create Drawable objects in code.