# Android Shape Drawable changing attributes

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I have several shape drawable resourses that I want use as backround for buttons and they are similar except gradient start and end color and stroke color.
The problem is that I don't want to create several similar XML files for this drawables.

I throught that I can inherit shape drawable like a styles using  tag, but this is impossible.

I found this [Defining XML Parent Style of Gradient / Shape / Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630206/defining-xml-parent-style-of-gradient-shape-corners?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but I don't understand how it's working. How he changing attributes values?

There [Using parents for drawable resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758768/using-parents-for-drawable-resources) I found that I can change appearance of background by layer-list that will draw layers of drawables one on top of another. But how manipulate with gradient and stroke color using layer-list?

I found that I can change appearance of buttons background in runtime, but probably there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Implement the `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory.resize()` create a new `LinearGradient` object which is a subclass of `Shader`, then return that object. Then call `ShapeDrawable.setShader()` pass it your implementation of the `ShaderFactory`. There is no way to change the attributes for the gradients, you have to redraw the colors to update them. Sorry, I dont have my laptop

Comment: thanks for advice, I will try this and reply. Can you post a tiny example when you'll have you laptop? It will be very helpful for me and I'll be grateful

Comment: are you sure that this correctly works for Eclipce?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but in the mean time, you should check the docs for `ShapeDrawable.setShader()` and also `ShaderFactory`and `Shader`, pretty self explanatory. Haha, it doesnt matter which IDE, also, Eclipse is the history already, you should switch to Android Studio, it is smarter, has a more efficient way to add and manage you dependencies and more more. Also Google will stop supporting Eclipse, AS is the next gen

Comment: Also, check out the subclasses of `Shader`, you'll need them

Comment: of course I will check this docs and thanks for explanation about Android Studio. I will answer you when I done this

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the initial suggestion I made is not feasible. I thought the `<shape>` will return a `ShapeDrawable` but I was wrong, here is how I would modify the gradient.

Before the button is clicked
[image: before]

After the button is clicked, its background changes.
[image: after]

This is the Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    // you can use the GradientDrawable directly, check the docs for details,
                    // I extended GradientDrawable just to make myself look like a badass :)

                    MyReflection.invokeMethod(button, new Gradient(), "setBackground");
                } 

                catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                catch (InvocationTargetException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

     }
}
```

Utility method to get a new method with the an object to invoke the method on, the `Drawable` to use as the new background, and the name of the method without the `()` such as `setBackground` to run on older versions. Reflection is SLOW. Use it sparingly.

```
/*
* We want to use reflection because the View.setBackground() method
* is only available on API level 16 and up.
* If you don't understand this, you can follow the tutorial provided by
* Oracle, just search for it on Google with the keyword "reflection tutorial"
*/

public class MyReflection {

    public static void invokeMethod(Object receiverObject, Drawable background, String methodName)
            throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Class<?> clazz = View.class;

        Method method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, Drawable.class);

        // Allowing non-public access call to this method.
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(receiverObject, background);
    }
}
```

My custom gradient

```
/**
* I am extending the GradientDrawable just for fun, and also
* because I want to set the shader property for this drawable,
* you could, however, use the GradientDrawable directly.
*/
public class Gradient extends GradientDrawable {

    private Paint paint;
    private LinearGradient gradient;

    public Gradient()
    {
        super();
        // check the docs for LinearGradient for these parameters
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0,0, 100, 100, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN,   Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(gradient);
    }

    public Gradient(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation, int[] colors)
    {
        super(orientation, colors);
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0,0, 100, 100, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(gradient);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }
}
```

The initial background for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The initial shape with just a solid yellow color -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#ff0"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: I had some business yesterday and I have no time to open stack and view your answer so sorry about this

Comment: p.s. I understand RTTI mechanism and especially thanks for screenshots and comments

Comment: Lol, dont be sorry, remember, calling new APIs this way using reflection will not make your app crash when an old version accesses it, but slow, check this to learn about other techniques http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html?m=1

Comment: thanks for doc (about compatibilities) can I later show you my buttons, made by this way? and rather later my project?

Comment: can I find you in facebook or can you give me your email? because I can't currently post images there (because of my rate)

Comment: It is billvan.1992@gmail.com, I use this one to protect my main one

Answer (score 0):

hah, instead of using Reflections I used this code, based on current version, to set appropriative background

```
int sdk = android.os.Built.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```